# doing a foreach on queries using codeigntier?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, model

I'm trying to do a `foreach` on my model using **codeigniter**, but it's giving me an error and returning the results.

Here's the code:

```
public function read(){
        $questions; //array
        $query = $this->db->get('questions');
        foreach($query->result() as $row){
            $getAnswers = $this->db->get_where('answers', array('question_id'=>$row['question_id]']), 4);
            $questions= $getAnswers;

           }

        return $questions;
     }
```

and this is the error:

> Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in

Comment: $getAnswers= $this-db ...... basically 5

Comment: I think the part in your foreach should be $questions[] = $getAnswers; otherwise you are only going to have the last row... you can also properly create the array before your foreach.... $questions = array(); --- just something i noticed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Access `row` as an object:

```
$getAnswers = $this->db->get_where('answers', 
                   array('question_id'=>$row->question_id), 4);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, that works, but can i ask you im returning the questions object array right, because its saying its wrong thanks +1 from me

Comment: Or use `$query->result_array()` instead of `$query->result()`.

Comment: @user1551482, this answer fixes the error, but the way you are trying to retrieve questions and answers has many flaws. Have a look at joins.

Comment: Glad it helped. @user1551482 You are erasing the data on each iteration. Either use joins as Mischa suggested, or use `array_push($questions, $getAnswers);`. Joins are much better.